# Using Property files in Spring 4 MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have some properties that I have put in a property file config.properties in the dir resources/config.config.properties.

I have the servlet.xml spring config file in the resources dir. It has this line

```
<util:properties id="nodeProperty"
        location="classpath:config/config.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="nodeProperty"/>
```

In my controller I want to use the property from the file. Hence I have this line

```
   @Autowired
        @Value ("${paths.root}")
private  String rootPath;
```

later in a web method I am saying

```
 String rootPath =  rootPath;
```

For this line I am getting the variable not initialized error for compiling.

If anyone has any solutions to this problem please let me know..

Comment: any one?? any sugession

Comment: Typo `config.config.properties`?

Comment: no, it is in config dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue using a q posted on stackoverflow. Added the following line in the servlet.xml

```
<util:properties id="someid" location="classpath:config/config.properties"/>
```

and then in my controller

```
private @Value("#{someid['paths.root']}") String rootPath;
```

Removed the @autowired and it worked!